# Как разместить на своём сайте плеер заблокированого провайдером видеобалансера чтобы он работал?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vds, плеер

Есть такой вопрос, у меня почти все видеобалансеры заблокированы провайдером, можно ли как то сделать чтобы разместив плеер на своём сайте он работал, как то проксировать может? Может кто имел с подобным дело?
Спасибо!

Comment: как-то проксировать

Comment: Так можно это как то реализовать или нет? Средствами nodejs или nginx?

Comment: посылай запросы на сервак с другим местоположением, на том серваке пропиши запросы к видеобалансеру и ответ от балансера возвращай обратно на свой, со своего на клиент

Comment: Я неверно объяснил. Есть пользователь, у которого скажем так заблокирован доступ почти ко всему, но есть доступ к моему сайту, на сайте фильмы с видеобалансера который предоставляет плеер в iframe. Получается у пользователя сайт открывается а видео нет, это как то можно обойти не прибегая со стороны пользователя к таким технологиям как впн.